# Meaning of the phrase 'going away' in the sense of travel

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Let's go away for a few days. 
>   Let's get away for a few days.

Can both the sentences be used to mean?

> Let's go on vacation for a few days.

Please, explain

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can both be used to mean go on vacation (AmEng), or on holiday (BrEng). There really isn't much explanation as to *why* they mean this, except to say they have both become idiomatic.

If there is any difference between the two expressions, it is subtle - but "go away" sounds more like you are thinking positively about your destination, whereas "get away" perhaps sounds a little more like you are trying to escape your normal routine.

Interestingly, the compound word "*getaway*" can be used to describe either a vacation, or a vacation destination.